# Python read file contents into nested list

Tags: python-3.x

I have this file that contains something like this:

`OOOOOOXOOOO
OOOOOXOOOOO
OOOOXOOOOOO
XXOOXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO`

And I need to read it into a 2D list so it looks like this:

```
[[O,O,O,O,O,O,X,O,O,O,O],[O,O,O,O,O,X,O,O,O,O,O],[O,O,O,O,X,O,O,O,O,O,O],[X,X,O,O,X,O,O,O,O,O,O],[X,X,X,X,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O],[O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O,O]
```

I have this code:

```
ins = open(filename, "r" )
data = []
for line in ins:
    number_strings = line.split() # Split the line on runs of whitespace
    numbers = [(n) for n in number_strings]
    data.append(numbers) # Add the "row" to your list.
return data
```

But it doesn't seem to be working because the O's and X's do not have spaces between them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `data.append(list(line.rstrip()))` list accepts a string as argument and just splits them on every character.

Comment: You were right, changed the answer according to recognize whitespace.